# remove certain keys from an assoc. array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$pool = array(
     'foo' => array('foobar1'),
     'bar' => array('foobar2'),
     'lou' => array('foobar3'),
     'zuu' => array('foobar4') 
);

$remove = array('lou', 'zuu');
```

How do I get this array:

```
$result = array(
     'foo' => array('foobar1'),
     'bar' => array('foobar2')
);
```

I can do a foreach loop but I like a more elegant solution like

```
$result = array_intersect_key( $pool, array_flip($remove) );
```

which gives me the other way:

```
array(
     'lou' => array('foobar3'),
     'zuu' => array('foobar4')
);
```

**EDIT**: my one line solution is:

```
array_intersect_key( $pool, array_flip( array_keys( array_diff_key( $pool, array_flip( $remove ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this then

```
 $pool = array(
     'foo' => array('foobar1'),
     'bar' => array('foobar2'),
     'lou' => array('foobar3'),
     'zuu' => array('foobar4') 
);

$remove = array('lou', 'zuu');
$compare=array_diff_key($pool, array_flip($remove));
var_dump(array_intersect_key($pool,$compare));
```

Comment: That requires a loop, as mentioned I prefer a different solution

Comment: Like it! In one line its `array_intersect_key($pool, array_flip(array_keys(array_diff_key($pool, array_flip($remove)))))`

Comment: i have optimized it. use optimized one

Answer (score 2):

Use unset function

```
unset($pool['lou']);
```